# How can other defmodules import defclass and deftemplate from MAIN

Tags: clips

I recently have read a paper that used CLIPS to implement automatic detection. And partial code is shown in it.  It shows that all the defclasses belong to MAIN module. But in other defmodules, their's defrules can used these defclass . In the advanced.docx, it says"the predefined MAIN module does not import or export any constructs". And I also have testified in the CLIPS interfaces.

For example:

```
(defclass MAIN::telemetry-data
      (is-a USER)
      (slot name(type SYMBOL))
      (slot predict-value(type SYMBOL NUMBER)))



(defrule discrimination::analog-data-discriminate
(object (is-a telemetry-data ) (name ?name))
 =>
 (printout t "name:"?name crlf)
)
```

So how can the defrule use  telemetry-data object without error?
I know I can definite the class within the discrimination module in order to execute right.  But I just wonder if there are some other ways to use the construct definited in the MAIN module by other defmodules.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the relevant passage from section 10.1 of the Basic Programming Guide:

> All of the predefined system classes (see section 9.2) belong to the
>   MAIN module. However, it is not necessary to import or export the
>   system classes; they are always in scope. Discounting the previous
>   exception, the predefined MAIN module does not import or export any
>   constructs. However, unlike other modules, the MAIN module can be
>   redefined once after startup or a clear command.

All you have to do is redefine the MAIN module:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (defmodule MAIN (export ?ALL))
CLIPS> 
(defclass MAIN::telemetry-data
   (is-a USER)
   (slot predict-value))
CLIPS> 
(defmodule discrimination (import MAIN ?ALL))
CLIPS> 
(defrule discrimination::analog-data-discriminate
   (object (is-a telemetry-data) (name ?name))
   =>
   (printout t "name: " ?name crlf))
CLIPS>
```

The code snippet you provided has other issues. The type definitions are OK, but the name slot is already predefined for a class.